# Propel PHP indexing returns only first array

Tags: php, arrays, propel

I'm trying to use Propel's ORM system to create an Api.
Everything works fine but I would need the return to be indexed by file_id instead of the 0,1,2,3,4

Propel has a built in function for this

```
$files = FilesQuery::create()->find()->toArray('file_id');
```

While there are 5 arrays within **$files** it returns only the first array within **$files** indexed properly.

Anyone any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Please provide clarification on the data structure of the table, the 5 subject rows, and what "indexed properly" means for you.

Comment: Doesn't make sense.  You should get the same results with only the difference being indexes.  So a sample clarification will shed some light.

Comment: I'll provide a sample later today